# using "overall" groups after facet_wrap (gepolt)

Tags: r, ggplot2, compare, facet, anova

I want to add a bar (with significance) to my ggplot.
I know the code for adding the bar (stat_pvalue_manual()) but my problem is of more general nature. Is it possible to use "overall" groups after a facet_wrap?

My code is the following:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)
data <-mtcars[,c(1,2)]
data <- data[c(1:30),]
setDT(data, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
data <- as.data.frame(data[,c(1,2)])
data$group <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
data$group2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
data$mpg2 <- data$mpg * 0.6345
data$mp3 <- data$mpg * 0.7564
data$group <- as.factor(data$group)
data$group2 <- as.factor(data$group2)


long_data <- melt(setDT(data), id.vars = c("rn", "group", "group2"), variable.name = "Timepoint")

p <- ggplot(long_data, aes(x = Timepoint, y = value, fill = group2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean", position = "dodge", na.rm = T, alpha=0.35) +
  geom_point(data = long_data %>% filter(group=="1") , aes(x = Timepoint, y = value, colour =  group),  size = 0.9, shape = 16)+
  geom_point(data = long_data %>% filter(group=="2") ,aes(x = Timepoint, y = value, colour =  group),  size = 0.9, shape = 16)+
  geom_point(data = long_data %>% filter(group=="3") ,aes(x = Timepoint, y = value, colour =  group),  size = 0.9, shape = 17)+
  geom_line(data = long_data, aes(x= Timepoint, y = value, group = rn),  alpha = .3, size = 0.4) +
  facet_wrap(~group2)



p
```

I want to "use" both groups and add a bar between group 1 and 2 (which are separated by the facet_wrap). I attach a picture of what the plot gives me and manually draw in red what I would want.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way round this problem is to overlay two plots on top of each other using `patchwork`. One plot will have to have only a `geom_signif` layer, the other is your existing plot:

```r
library(ggpubr)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(long_data, aes(x = Timepoint, y = value, colour = group)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = group2), color = NA, stat = "summary", fun = "mean", 
           position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE, alpha = 0.35) +
  geom_point(data = filter(long_data, group == "1"), size = 0.9, shape = 16) +
  geom_point(data = filter(long_data, group == "2"), size = 0.9, shape = 16) +
  geom_point(data = filter(long_data, group == "3"), size = 0.9, shape = 17) +
  geom_line(data = long_data, aes(group = rn), color = 'black',
            alpha = 0.3, size = 0.4) +
  facet_wrap(~group2) +
  ylim(c(0, 40))

p2 <- ggplot(long_data, aes(group2, value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'summary', fun = 'mean', fill = NA) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c('1', '2')), test = 't.test',
              map_signif_level = function(p) sprintf("p = %.2g", p),
              extend_line = 0.025, y_position = 37, vjust = -0.2) +
  ylim(c(0, 40)) +
  theme_void()
```

Now we draw `p1` and put `p2` directly on top of it:

```r
layout <- c(
  area(t = 1, l = 1, b = 2, r = 2),
  area(t = 1, l = 1, b = 2, r = 2)
)

p1 + p2 + plot_layout(design = layout)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I realised my original post was maybe missing an important aspect. I thought it was clear from the picture but I don't think the picture describes it sufficiently. The bar (with significance) is supposed to represent the result of an ANOVA. To be exact it is supposed to represent the results (p-value) of the interaction of group2 and Timepoint. The ANOVA it self I calculated and I have the p-value but I don't know how to add the results in a way that the bar is drawn for for the two groups and not within one group

Comment: @NimaH. so do you want just the image above with a different p value that you have already calculated? If so, and say your p value was 0.02, you would just change `map_signif_level` in the above code to something like `map_signif_level = function(p) 'Anova results p = 0.02'`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the significance bar, perhaps it would be easier and just as clear to add bars for the overall group means in the two facets, such as `geom_crossbar(aes(group = group2), color = "black")`. Then the overlap of the error bars can signal the size of the differences across panels.